# Strong name assembly required only since .NET 4.0

Tags: .net, office-interop, excel-interop, strongname

I have an old application originally build against .NET 2.0 that used Office 97 Interop and it worked. When it was upgraded to .NET 4.0 the application crashed when it tried to load the Excel Interop with error:

```
System.IO.FileLoadException: Could not load file or assembly 'Interop.Office, Version=2.1.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=null' or one of its dependencies. A strongly-named assembly is required. (Exception from HRESULT: 0x80131044)
File name: 'Interop.Office, Version=2.1.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=null'
```

I was able to reproduce the issue with a very simple new application. The exception occurs whenever calling a method that instantiates an `Excel.Application` object. The application references the following libraries:

```
<Reference Include="Interop.Excel, Version=1.3.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=5d41fe291391dcf0">
  <HintPath>..\..\Thirdparty\Microsoft\Office\97\Interop.Excel.dll</HintPath>
</Reference>
<Reference Include="System" />
<Reference Include="System.Drawing" />
<Reference Include="System.Windows.Forms" />
```

The **Interop.Excel.dll** library is in the application's folder and *it's strongly-named*. Here's its manifest:

```
// Metadata version: v1.1.4322
.assembly extern mscorlib
{
  .publickeytoken = (B7 7A 5C 56 19 34 E0 89 )                         // .z\V.4..
  .ver 1:0:5000:0
}
.assembly extern Interop.Office
{
  .ver 2:1:0:0
}
.assembly extern Microsoft.Vbe.Interop
{
  .publickeytoken = (71 E9 BC E1 11 E9 42 9C )                         // q.....B.
  .ver 11:0:0:0
}
.assembly Interop.Excel
{
  ...
  .hash algorithm 0x00008004
  .ver 1:3:0:0
}
```

There is no other library in the application's folder. There is **Interop.Office.dll** in a Thirdparty folder with the following manifest:

```
// Metadata version: v1.1.4322
.assembly extern mscorlib
{
  .publickeytoken = (B7 7A 5C 56 19 34 E0 89 )                         // .z\V.4..
  .ver 1:0:5000:0
}
.assembly Interop.Office
{
  ...
  .hash algorithm 0x00008004
  .ver 2:0:0:0
}
```

It is *not strongly-named*.

Summarising, when the application is built against .NET 2.0 or .NET 3.5, it runs fine and interacts with Excel without any exception. After changing its target Framework to .NET 4.0 or .NET 4.5.1, it crashes with the exception mentioned above. It makes no difference whether the application itself is strongly-named or not. I am not aware of any breaking changes in .NET 4.0 that would affect it.

Moreover, no configuration flag in **app.config** when in .NET 4.0 seems to help:

```
<runtime>
  <bypassTrustedAppStrongNames enabled="true"/>
  <NetFx40_LegacySecurityPolicy enabled="true"/>
  <legacyCasPolicy enabled="true"/>
  <loadFromRemoteSources enabled="true"/>
</runtime>
```

I have no idea where *Interop.Excel.dll* tries to load *Interop.Office.dll* from and why it succeeds in .NET 2.0 and fails in .NET 4.0. Neither *Fusion Log* nor *Process Monitor* are able to detect any loading of the latter library. I'm attaching the Fusion logs below if they might be helpful:

When run in .NET 2.0:

```
*** Assembly Binder Log Entry  (31/07/2014 @ 09:43:49) ***

The operation failed.
Bind result: hr = 0x80070002. The system cannot find the file specified.

Assembly manager loaded from:  C:\Windows\Microsoft.NET\Framework64\v2.0.50727\mscorwks.dll
Running under executable  C:\tmp\WindowsFormsApplication2\WindowsFormsApplication2\bin\Debug\WindowsFormsApplication2.exe
--- A detailed error log follows. 

=== Pre-bind state information ===
LOG: User = domain\user
LOG: DisplayName = Interop.Excel, Version=1.3.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=5d41fe291391dcf0
 (Fully-specified)
LOG: Appbase = file:///C:/tmp/WindowsFormsApplication2/WindowsFormsApplication2/bin/Debug/
LOG: Initial PrivatePath = NULL
LOG: Dynamic Base = NULL
LOG: Cache Base = NULL
LOG: AppName = NULL
Calling assembly : WindowsFormsApplication2, Version=1.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=null.
===
LOG: Start binding of native image Interop.Excel, Version=1.3.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=5d41fe291391dcf0.
WRN: No matching native image found.
```

When run in .NET 4.0:

```
*** Assembly Binder Log Entry  (31/07/2014 @ 09:43:08) ***

The operation was successful.
Bind result: hr = 0x1. Incorrect function.

Assembly manager loaded from:  C:\Windows\Microsoft.NET\Framework64\v4.0.30319\clr.dll
Running under executable  C:\tmp\WindowsFormsApplication2\WindowsFormsApplication2\bin\Debug\WindowsFormsApplication2.exe
--- A detailed error log follows. 

BEGIN : Native image bind.
END   : Incorrect function. (Exception from HRESULT: 0x00000001 (S_FALSE))


*** Assembly Binder Log Entry  (31/07/2014 @ 09:43:08) ***

The operation was successful.
Bind result: hr = 0x0. The operation completed successfully.

Assembly manager loaded from:  C:\Windows\Microsoft.NET\Framework64\v4.0.30319\clr.dll
Running under executable  C:\tmp\WindowsFormsApplication2\WindowsFormsApplication2\bin\Debug\WindowsFormsApplication2.exe
--- A detailed error log follows. 

=== Pre-bind state information ===
LOG: DisplayName = Interop.Excel, Version=1.3.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=5d41fe291391dcf0
 (Fully-specified)
LOG: Appbase = file:///C:/tmp/WindowsFormsApplication2/WindowsFormsApplication2/bin/Debug/
LOG: Initial PrivatePath = NULL
LOG: Dynamic Base = NULL
LOG: Cache Base = NULL
LOG: AppName = WindowsFormsApplication2.exe
Calling assembly : WindowsFormsApplication2, Version=1.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=null.
===
WRN: No matching native image found.
LOG: IL assembly loaded from C:\tmp\WindowsFormsApplication2\WindowsFormsApplication2\bin\Debug\Interop.Excel.dll.


*** Assembly Binder Log Entry  (31/07/2014 @ 09:43:08) ***

The operation was successful.
Bind result: hr = 0x0. The operation completed successfully.

Assembly manager loaded from:  C:\Windows\Microsoft.NET\Framework64\v4.0.30319\clr.dll
Running under executable  C:\tmp\WindowsFormsApplication2\WindowsFormsApplication2\bin\Debug\WindowsFormsApplication2.exe
--- A detailed error log follows. 

=== Pre-bind state information ===
LOG: DisplayName = Interop.Excel, Version=1.3.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=5d41fe291391dcf0
 (Fully-specified)
LOG: Appbase = file:///C:/tmp/WindowsFormsApplication2/WindowsFormsApplication2/bin/Debug/
LOG: Initial PrivatePath = NULL
LOG: Dynamic Base = NULL
LOG: Cache Base = NULL
LOG: AppName = WindowsFormsApplication2.exe
Calling assembly : WindowsFormsApplication2, Version=1.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=null.
===
WRN: No matching native image found.
LOG: IL assembly loaded from C:\tmp\WindowsFormsApplication2\WindowsFormsApplication2\bin\Debug\Interop.Excel.dll.
```

### EDIT

I have found <strike>a workaround</strike> by using the *useLegacyV2RuntimeActivationPolicy* attribute in *app.config*:

```
<startup useLegacyV2RuntimeActivationPolicy="true">
  <supportedRuntime version="v4.0" sku=".NETFramework,Version=v4.0"/>
</startup>
```

More information on the attribute can be found here:

- [useLegacyV2RuntimeActivationPolicy on MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bbx34a2h(VS.100).aspx)
- [useLegacyV2RuntimeActivationPolicy by Marklio](http://web.archive.org/web/20130128072944/http://www.marklio.com/marklio/PermaLink,guid,ecc34c3c-be44-4422-86b7-900900e451f9.aspx)

Although <strike>it seems to help and its meaning seems to be valid</strike> (running legacy components after migration to .NET 4.0), it also disables [Side-by-Side Execution for COM Interop](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/8t8td04t(v=vs.100).aspx). <strike>**Shouldn't it be enabled (and the attribute avoided) when using Office Interops?**</strike>

### EDIT

The previous workaround actually did not work. It seemed to, but it was caused by other change and not because of the attribute. Namely, I re-added the **Interop.Excel.dll** library to the project which automatically set *Embed Interop Types* to *True*. When the library is embedded it does work and interacts with Excel. I don't want to embed it, though.

Comment: Have you tried removing the COM reference and adding it again? It might help build a correct interop library.

Comment: No, because I don't have access to the original Excel 97 libraries and even if I did, this particular case does not allow us to deploy new libraries for that old application.

Comment: You keep focusing on the interop library that doesn't have this problem.  It is *not* Interop.Excel.dll, it loads just fine as your Fuslogvw.exe trace shows.  It is Interop.Office.dll that is the troublemaker.  It indeed doesn't have a strong-name.  This problem started a very long time ago when somebody made the copy in Thirdparty\Microsoft\Office\97.  Having trouble with a .NET 1.0 assembly isn't that strange, rebuilding it and taking advantage of the Embed Interop Types feature is strongly recommended.

Comment: Yes, embedding the old assembly helps (but it's available in .NET 4). I don't have sources to Excel.dll 97 to rebuild the Interop. Anyway, I cannot modify that old application. We have a "launcher" application written in .NET 4.0 (previously 2.0) that starts the old application in an AppDomain. When the launcher was in .NET 2.0 it worked fine. Now it loads CLR 4.0, then loads the old app in .NET 2.0 in a separate AppDomain (still CLR 4, however). In this situation an attempt to export data to Excel from the application causes the error I mentioned on the top.